# How to use Scala plugin for IntelliJ on Debian?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, debian

I have IntelliJ Idea Community Edition v 123.72, with Scala Plugin 0.6.371 on an Debian unstable box that has packages scala and scala-library v 2.9.2+dfsg-1. When creating a new Scala module, I am asked for either "SCALA_HOME" or an "Existent Library" with two empty drop downs for "compiler library" and "standard library".

Is it possible to use the distro scala packages with the plugin? If so, how do I fill out the 
"new project form"?

If not, where do I find a Linux binary distro of Scala?

(It all seems straight-forward, but my Google-fu fails me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest version of Scala [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads) and then set scala home to the unzipped directory (can be anywhere). IntelliJ will take care of the rest.

Comment: Which bundle exactly? There is no Linux binaries?

Comment: @Bittrance Right, this [file](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-2.10.0.tgz) is the one you want. Simply unzip it into a directory called `scala-2.10.0`, for example, and point IntelliJ to it and it will figure out which libraries to use in `scala-compiler` and which to use in `scala-library`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, recreate the directory structure that intelliJ is looking for by using mkdir and ln -s.

The Debian package manager installs bits and pieces of scala all over the root directory. I found the libs that intelliJ is looking for in /usr/share/java

To create system links and satisfy intelliJ you can try the following:

```
mkdir /usr/share/java/lib
ln -s /usr/share/java/scala-library-X.X.X.jar /usr/share/java/lib/scala-library.jar
ln -s /usr/share/java/scala-compiler-X.X.X.jar /usr/share/java/lib/scala-compiler.jar
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/share/java
```

Why aptitude drops scala nuggets all over the place, instead of a more common, central location such as /usr/lib/scala remains a mystery to me. Anyone?

Comment: It's pretty standard; executables go in /usr/bin, documentation in /usr/share/doc, man pages in /usr/share/man, and I suppose maven wants its files where the page puts them. JAR files goes in /usr/share/java. /usr/lib would be wrong; that's for architecture-specific files, and JARs don't need to be recompiled for each separate port.